# How to manage Firebase Instance ID's

Tags: android, firebase

I'm creating an app which collects data (Weight, age, gender).
I'm going to add an InstanceID (or generate some kind of ID which identifies users device). DeviceID will be shown for the user in the app.

- What happens when user deletes the app?
- If user has deleted the app and still asks me to show the data what app has collected how can I do that, if the user doesn't know his deviceId?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no need for that. Please check the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase authentication sets an ID for that authenticated user, so even if the user deletes the app and then uses the app again by same email Id authentication , then the UID that FirebaseInstance would return would be the same. So to sum it up, the UID for an user is linked to the authentication (email id) and not with the device.

Comment: Ok I understand, is it possible to NOT use emails but only Device Instance ID or some sort?

Comment: Firebase allows authentication through an email(also Google/Facebook/Github Sign in) .I'm afraid there's no such way that you are interjecting and if you want to do something like that then you will not be able to retrieve the data once you uninstall.However, you could just generate a random UID for a device without using an email.

Comment: Do you know if I'm still eligible to provide the data if the user have removed the app and forgot the id? Can he / she take some legal action?